# Default value for foreign key column - InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, default-value

Take the following SQL fiddle:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae0df/1

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vatbands` (
  `vatbands_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` ENUM('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F') NOT NULL,
  `client_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vatbands_id`, `code`, `client_id`),
  INDEX `vatcode_vatbands` (`code` ASC, `client_id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item` (
  `item_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer ID',
  `vatcode` ENUM('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F') DEFAULT 'A',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`, `client_id`),
  INDEX `vatcode_item` (`vatcode` ASC, `client_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `vatcode_item`
    FOREIGN KEY (`vatcode` , `client_id`)
    REFERENCES `sbs_node`.`vatbands` (`code` , `client_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `vatbands` (`client_id`, `code`) VALUES ('1', 'A');
INSERT INTO `item` (`client_id`, `vatcode`) VALUES ('1', NULL);
COMMIT;
```

Why is the `vatcode` column 'null' when a default value of 'A' is specified?

Comment: Would the creepy down voter like to leave a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of the ENUM type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html) states:

> If an ENUM column is declared to permit NULL, the NULL value is a
>   valid value for the column, and the default value is NULL. If an ENUM
>   column is declared NOT NULL, its default value is the first element of
>   the list of permitted values.

Your INSERT is using the NULL value:

```
INSERT INTO `item` (`client_id`, `vatcode`) VALUES ('1', NULL);
```

Change your `CREATE TABLE` statement to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item` (
  `item_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer ID',
  `vatcode` ENUM('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F') NOT NULL,        -- no default, but NOT NULL           
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`, `client_id`),
  INDEX `vatcode_item` (`vatcode` ASC, `client_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `vatcode_item`
    FOREIGN KEY (`vatcode` , `client_id`)
    REFERENCES `vatbands` (`code` , `client_id`)     -- corrected that one too
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

and your INSERT statement to:

```
INSERT INTO `item` (`client_id`, `vatcode`) VALUES ('1', DEFAULT);
```

to get the result you want, see [my updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b85a/1).